# dimension of $V = \{[x] \times [y]\in \mathbb{P}^N \times \mathbb{P}^N : \text{for all } \lambda,\mu \in K, F(x\lambda+y\mu)=0\}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hey because of stupidity and little knowledge of this forum my question([Vanishing set of a homogeneous polynomial containing projective lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359338/vanishing-set-of-a-homogeneous-polynomial-containing-projective-lines)) got blocked.

Let K be an algebraically closed field.
Let $F \in K[X_0,..,X_N]$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $ m > 0 $ and let $Z = V(F)$. Let $V = \{[x] \times [y]\in \mathbb{P}^N \times \mathbb{P}^N : \text{for all } \lambda,\mu \in K, F(x\lambda+y\mu)=0\}$ be the closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^N \times \mathbb{P}^N $.

Question 1
Show that $ \dim(V) \geq 2N-m-1$

Now let $\Delta=\{(x,x): x\in \mathbb{P}^N\}$.

> My try:
>   I'm not sure how we can use the theory about dimension in
>   $\mathbb{P}^N \times \mathbb{P}^N$, I want to reduce the dimension of
>   V at least locally with the theorem about dimension using m+1
>   equations. But this theory holds in my knowledge only for a
>   $\mathbb{P}^M$... The second question is okay. For the third I know
>   that for $m < N$ it holds that $\dim V > \dim(\Delta \cap V)$ and with
>   that I somehow need to find that projective line

Could I have some tips for the different questions?